# Playing a video as a camera in AppRTCDemo

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, webrtc, yuv

I need to run an experiment in WebRTC on Android so that I found a useful Android source application AppRTCDemo (https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc). It uses a WebRTC library (libjingle_peerconnection) which supports to open a video as a camera. It can be determined in the AppRTCDemo source code by a variable `EXTRA_VIDEO_FILE_AS_CAMERA`.

```
CallActivity.java (AppRTCDemo);
private VideoCapturer createVideoCapturer();
videoCapturer = new FileVideoCapturer(videoFileAsCamera);
```

When I open a video (.mp4, .avi) in the application it has an error "Does not support any other color space than I420 or I420mpeg2". After spending a couple of hours, I found that the library only supports YUV file with the color space is I420. So that I've tried to find that file but when It comes to run, there has another error "Found end of file before end of header for file".

The source file as the following:

```
public VideoReaderY4M(String file) throws IOException {
        this.mediaFileStream = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        while(true) {
            int header = this.mediaFileStream.read();
            if(header == -1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Found end of file before end of header for file: " + file);
            }

            if(header == 10) {
                this.videoStart = this.mediaFileStream.getFilePointer();
                String var13 = builder.toString();
                String[] headerTokens = var13.split("[ ]");
                int w = 0;
                int h = 0;
                String colorSpace = "";
                String[] arr$ = headerTokens;
                int len$ = headerTokens.length;

                for(int i$ = 0; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
                    String tok = arr$[i$];
                    char c = tok.charAt(0);
                    switch(c) {
                    case 'C':
                        colorSpace = tok.substring(1);
                        break;
                    case 'H':
                        h = Integer.parseInt(tok.substring(1));
                        break;
                    case 'W':
                        w = Integer.parseInt(tok.substring(1));
                    }
                }

                Logging.d("VideoReaderY4M", "Color space: " + colorSpace);
                if(!colorSpace.equals("420") && !colorSpace.equals("420mpeg2")) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does not support any other color space than I420 or I420mpeg2");
                }

                if(w % 2 != 1 && h % 2 != 1) {
                    this.frameWidth = w;
                    this.frameHeight = h;
                    this.frameSize = w * h * 3 / 2;
                    Logging.d("VideoReaderY4M", "frame dim: (" + w + ", " + h + ") frameSize: " + this.frameSize);
                    return;
                }

                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Does not support odd width or height");
            }

            builder.append((char)header);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @JohnPekl , did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @RickSanchez  
open   org.appspot.apprtc  file  and edit it

before ->
String colorSpace = "";
after -> 
String colorSpace = "420";

Answer (score 0):

Add a default value for colorSpace; sometimes the header in y4m format that is parsed may not contain colorSpace.
example：String colorSpace = "420";

Answer (score 0):

[image]

recreate create FileVideoCapture.java
and edit it